# Dealing with javascript in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the "popover" to work for Bootstrap. I believe my code is correct but I am not to sure about the javascript part. Below is what is included inside my head - importing the javascripts - and how my tag looks like. Thank you for the help!

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/JSForFinal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and inside my JFForFinal.js

```
 $("a[rel=popover]").popover('show');
```

my tag inside my body tag looks like this:

```
      <a href="#" rel="popover" data-placement="right" data-original-title="popover on     
      right">Stuff</a>
```

I feel like everything is correct but when I click on the button, nothing pops up. Thank you!

Comment: For starters, you're loading multiple copies of jQuery. Don't do that.

Comment: What do you mean? like for the first script? I did not want to include it but I thought it would solve my problem

Comment: move the 4th item to first and remove the first item and try

Comment: Awesome job Arun, problem fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your js in the jquery document-ready incantation:

```
$(function() {
     $("a[rel=popover]").popover('show');
});
```

This is shorthand for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("a[rel=popover]").popover('show');
});
```

which tells jquery to defer execution until the document is ready.

If you want to defer execution until a button is clicked or something, then:

```
$(function() {
     $('#buttonid').click(function() {
         $("a[rel=popover]").popover('show');
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, but can you explain why it worked? I would rather know why then just use it. Thank you!

Comment: How can I stop it from showing initially, only activated when pressed on?

Comment: Using the bootstrap `.popover`, you don't need to wrap it in a click function. Instead of using `.popover('show')`, just use `.popover()`, which will register the elements with bootstrap, which should then handle the showing and hiding itself.